# Adding compiler to code::blocks

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

[image]From [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/) I've downloaded newest release of GCC, namely 4.6.
How can I add this compiler to my code::blocks?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to the Settings menu and hit Compiler and Debugger:

[image]

Go to Copy, and name the new compiler GCC 4.6 or whatever you'd like.  Go to the Toolchain Executables tab, and fill in the directory name.  I think all of the .exe's should be named the same thing.  Make sure and copy paste your linker settings from one to the other.  Now that compiler title will appear in all of the dialog boxes.  I'm not entirely sure how to move the new one up the list so it's the default.