# Error building boost with MinGW

Tags: c++, boost, mingw, mingw-w64

I tried to build boost library using the MinGW's GCC version that comes with CodeBLocks (gccc v5.1) and i have the bin folder in the PATH. When i run

```
boostrap.bat mingw
```

or

```
boostrap.bat gcc
```

i get

```
execnt.c: In function 'try_wait_callback':
execnt.c:833:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'UnregisterWait' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 UnregisterWait( slot->wait_handle );
```

Reading a litte someone told me that my gcc version doesn't work to build boost so then i downloaded the last MinGW-w64 and copy its bin folder content into the MinGW's bin folder trying to "cheat"

if i do
    gcc -v

i can see i have the version 7.3

Now it throws me this error:

```
gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

Comment: ***and copy its bin folder content into the MinGW's bin folder trying to "cheat"*** I would go back and install mingw correctly since the "cheat" method did not work.

Comment: I have backup the bin content that's not a problem.

Comment: No, Install the new version correctly. Going back to the old version will not solve your problem.

Comment: Into a separate directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use MinGW-w64, without the step "copy its bin folder content into the MinGW" !

You want to avoid using the pre-fork MinGW entirely. Download and install MinGW-w64 again and , if you want, [add it to Code::Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604183/adding-compiler-to-codeblocks).

Note that there are some sites providing MinGW-w64 and Boost bundles.

Comment: It works! By the way, when i tried to add MinGW-w64 i got some problems. It hadn't recognized the headers folders properly. I had to to make it looks like the MinGW folder system. I mean, simulate the folder distribution and their files.

Comment: @JavScars That's weird. On my machine an unmodified installation works fine.

Comment: Sorry for the late... I just give it up... I have installed Qt and everything works perfect

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with MinGW provided with Code::Block. So I have to add to recomendations important details.
To build Boost.build tool:

1. After installation of minGW-w64 in NEW directory you need to delete entry of old MinGW\bin directory from PATH environment variable and add new entry with something like  "C:\MinGW-w64\bin" entry.
2. By some reason starting commands in command line under user or administrator didn't work as supposed in Boost documentation, but if start terminal from shortcut provided by MinGW-w64 - commands of Boost can finish building. (Command "bootstrap.bat gcc")
3. Then Boost documentation recomends "b2 install --prefix=PREFIX" but I had to add parameter like "b2 install --prefix=PREFIX toolset=gcc" also in terminal started from MinGW-w64 shortcut.
4. Since I wanted to use MinGW32 of Code::Blocks in my projects (for other compatibility reasons), again I had to skip MinGW-w64 from availability (I had just renamed dir of MinGW-w64, you can delete entry from PATH) and to restore MinGW32 entry in PATH variable. Also I added Boost build tool "bin" dir into PATH.
   So I had got Boost.Build tool ready to use (builded by MinGW-w64 compiler)

To build Boost libraries' binaries:

5. Then I started terminal under administrator, changed dir to boost root directory and then use the last command like "b2 --build-dir=build-directory toolset=gcc --build-type=complete stage" (where build-directory is of your choice)

And at last I'd got the result:

...failed updating 1334 targets...

...skipped 732 targets...

...updated 2873 targets...

Where I could find necessary for me files of Boost filesystem like

libboost_filesystem-mgw51-mt-x32-1_67.dll

libboost_filesystem-mgw51-mt-s-x32-1_67.a

libboost_filesystem-mgw51-mt-x32-1_67.a

etc.

I didn't test them yet, but this can help to others to build Boost.